# What is wrong with my proof of Cayley-Hamilton? (First year Matrices course)

Tags: matrices, proof-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, fake-proofs

The characteristic equation of matrix A is p(t)=det(A-tI)

Then $$p(t)=\sum a_rt^r$$

for some coefficients a_r

Then $$p(A)=\sum a_r A^r$$

Let $$\vec{x}$$ be an eigenvector of A with eigenvalue t

But $$p(A) \vec{x} = \sum a_r A^{r} \vec{x} = \sum a_r A^{r-1}t \vec{x} = ... = \sum a_r t^r \vec{x} = det(A-tI) \vec{x} = 0$$

Where have I gone wrong? Much appreciated.

Comment: Well I don't see anything wrong there, but you didn't prove Cayley-Hamilton's theorem. You just proved that $p(A)x= 0$ for all eigenvectors of $A$. What you ought to show is that $p(A)=0$, in other words you need to prove that $p(A)x= 0$ for *any* vector

Comment: Well, now I feel stupid.

I'll try to remember to upvote when I get enough rep. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your argument works for case when $A$ is an diagonalizable matrix though,

Comment: @nonlinear Only once he proves that if $A $ is diagonalizable, then there is a basis for the underlying space consisting of eigenvectors of $A $.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo  What do you mean ? did say something wrong?

Comment: @nonlinear I mean precisely what I wrote. You did not say something wrong, not quite, but what the OP wrote is not enough, even if $A $ is diagonalizable.

Comment: Pay Attention: You have to show $p(A)=0$ in the set of matrices. What you've done is $p(A)=0$ in the real numbers, because $\det(A-tI)=0$ is a real number for some eigenvalue $t$.